# Is there any crash course for FogBUGZ?

Tags: fogbugz

Just [signed up for a trial](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) at fogcreek.com/Fogbugz after reading [Joel's latest blog post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/07/20.html). I think the features are very nice, but there are simply too many of them, and I'm having a hard time learning the platform.

Is there any online quick start guide or an one hour crash course that I can get started from?

I'm aware of a book called Painless Project Management with FogBugz, but how relevant is it to FogBugz 7.0?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest looking in the help of FogBugz itself, specifically [FogBugz in two minutes](https://joel.fogbugz.com/help/topics/basics/FogBugzintwominutes.html) and [The basics of bug tracking](https://joel.fogbugz.com/help/topics/basics/Thebasicsofbugtracking.html) sections. That would give you a quick grounding.

The second edition of the [FogBugz book by Mike Gunderloy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599144) was written for 6.0, but the core idea of how you use FogBugz on a team to track bugs and schedules is fundamentally the same, so this book is still quite worthwhile.

Fog Creek also runs [webinars which you can sign up for on their site](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) (see the WEBINAR tab).

Comment: thanks. It's actually at https://{{username}}.fogbugz.com/help/topics/basics/FogBugzintwominutes.html

Comment: Thanks Bo! I'm running a local installation, so don't know what the On Demand set up is like.

Answer (score 1):

There's a philosophy behind this program, that "there's nothing that you *have* to enter".  That means you can just jump in and start playing.  Part of the necessary learning curve is just getting used to the interface.  Once you're past that, the help, articles, and books make a lot more sense.